# NativeStorage gets cleared when I clear the cookie

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-cookie, cordova-nativestorage

I am trying to remove cookie using `$.removeCookie()` in my phonegap application, but it removes the `NativeStorage` (using the plugin [cordova-plugin-native-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage)) in my android.

The same problem repeats in IOS. But in IOS `NativeStorage` gets cleared once app is closed (even if I don't clear the cookie).

FYI : I am storing my login access token and few more details in cookies.

Any suggestion to keep the data to retain even if cookie is cleared?

Comment: What do you mean by `NativeStorage`? Do you use `cordova-plugin-native-storage` or something else?

Comment: @David Yes I am using it.

Comment: So if I understand that correctly the data you have saved in NativeStorage with `setItem('key', value)` is gone after you clear the cookies? That would be _very_ odd. I do not see any connection between the two, NativeStore items are saved on the native part (Sharedpreferences on android and NSUserDefaults on iOS) of your app and cookies are a webview thing.

Comment: @David yaah... I too got surprised to see it. I thought these plugin people might have configured cookie as fallback behavior

Comment: No that has to be something else in your code, you can check the plugins code on github, there is no fallback to cookies. Even in the browser local-storage is used as a "fallback" for testing.

Comment: yaah... I understand it... but still I dont know how the Native storage clears when I clear the cookie. Guess what? In IOS it is getting cleared when I close the app. How come it as the NSUserDefault behavior :(

Comment: Well I still don't think this has anything to do with the cookies, maybe you are calling NativeStoreges `clear()` method somewhere or some other cordova-plugin is infering. However jquery-cookie is deprecated since 2 years, you should use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) instead.